# How to install hawtio and the log plugin hawtio on servicemix 6.0?

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix, hawtio

Install hawtio on servicemix 6.0:

```
feature:repo-add mvn:io.hawt/hawtio-karaf/2.0.0/xml/features
install -s mvn:io.hawt/hawtio-maven-indexer/2.0.0*
feature:install hawtio
```

Install log plugin with hawtio:

```
install -s mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.6.0
install -s mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.6.0
install -s mvn:com.google.guava/guava/17.0
install -s mvn:io.fabric8/common-util/1.2.0.redhat-133
install -s mvn:io.fabric8/fabric8-utils/2.2.17
install -s mvn:io.fabric8.insight/insight-log/1.2.0.redhat-133
```

**Log plugin does not work!**

Comment: You should use hawtio 1.4.52. The 2.0.0 version was a mistake, its not ready yet for java in v2 yet - currently its html/rest based only.

Comment: Thank You, Claus! But log plugin hawtio 1.4.52 is not activated on servicemix 6.0 :(